# CSS: Float with multiline content: Minimal width

Tags: html, css, css-float

**Is it possible to have a floating element that has multiline content to take minimal width?**

Floating elements without a set width use up the least amount of width as long as their content is just one line. If it is more than one line, the width of the element is 100%.

#### My HTML

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="floater"> <a class="left" href="#">
            <span class="right">Right<br>Right<br>Right</span>
            <span class="inner">Left: longword longerword evenlongerword longerword evenlongerword longword.
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### My CSS

```css
.wrap {
    width: 350px;
    border: 1px solid gold;
}
.floater {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    padding: 5px;
}
.right {
    float:right;
    margin: 0 10px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    padding: 5px;
}
.inner {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

#### My fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/qBfbc/

#### My image

[image]

Comment: Why would any code distribute the words exactly like that and not in another way if it's not 100% wide?

Comment: @Itay I thought of that, too. Maybe there is a workaround not working with floats.

Comment: Are you interested in jQuery solutions?

Comment: You'd have to set width of about 270px on the left or inner container in order for it to wrap the words, otherwise it'll just use as much space as it can to fit the words in the existing space.

Comment: Did you meant the `right` class to be nested in the `left`, or is it a mistake?

Comment: The main problem is that the left floated element's content is not a multiline text. It is one line wrapped by the browser. So when the browser wraps your text it is not going to calculate a minimal width for your element containing the text, it would be an extreme overhead. So the only solution as far as I know, is that you set a fix width for your element, or accept that the browser uses all the available space.

Comment: @avrahamcool It's not a mistake.

Comment: @HerrSerker did my solution provide the layout you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a solution using JQuery

you can see this [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/BkpL2/) *Tested On:* IE10, IE9, IE8, FireFox, Chrome, Safari

**HTML:** (I changed it a little bit)

```
<div class="wrap"><a href="#">
        <span class="right">
            Right
            <br />
            Right
            <br />
            Right
        </span>
        <span class="inner">Left: longword longerword evenlongerword longerword evenlongerword longword.
        </span>
    </a></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
*
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrap
{
    width: 350px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid gold;
}

.wrap a
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    padding: 5px;
}
.right
{
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid green;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.inner
{
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$.fn.textwidth = function () {
    var html_org = $(this).html();
    var html_calc = '<span>' + html_org + '</span>';
    $(this).html(html_calc);
    var width = $(this).find('span:first').width();
    $(this).html(html_org);
    return width;
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".inner").width($(".inner").textwidth()+2);
});
```

**Edit:** a little bit more of Scripting to adjust the gray container as well
As can be seen at this [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/BkpL2/1/)

Comment: It somehow works, but not quite right. It's important that the 'right' element is directly next to the left element.

Comment: @HerrSerker Check out this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/BkpL2/1/)